# Find Elements by Attribute using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This query seems to be valid, but I have 0 results.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> users =
            (from el in XMLDoc.Elements("Users")
             where (string)el.Attribute("GUID") == userGUID.ToString()
             select el);
```

My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Users>
  <User GUID="68327fe2-d6f0-403b-a7b6-51860fbf0b2f">
    <Key ID="F7000012ECEAD101">
      ...
    </Key>
  </User>

</Users>
```

Do you have any clues to shed some light onto this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

change `Users` in the 2nd line to `User`.  Like this:

```
    IEnumerable<XElement> users = (from el in XMLDoc.Root.Elements("User")
                                   where (string)el.Attribute("GUID") ==  userGUID.ToString()
                                   select el);
```

I'm assuming XMLDoc is an XDocument, and not the root element itself.

Comment: Thanks, this was partly what I needed, a stupid mistake from me.

Comment: As Jon points out below, casting to the correct type is a better choice. Additionally, if you use "el.Attribute("GUID").Value" you automatically get a string as the return type and there is no need for the cast.

Comment: `root` should be `Root` in `XMLDoc.root.Elements("User")`.

Comment: I know this is an older post, but shouldn't it be 'where el.Attribute("GUID").Value == userGUID.ToString()' assuming that the userGUID is a GUID?

Comment: How would I achieve the same with a Sharepoint `_api` feed? I would like to get multiple child elements from each parent elements?

Answer (score 55):

Well, the *Users* elements don't have GUID attributes. Two suggested options:

- Look at `XDocument.Root.Elements("User")`
- Use `Descendants("User")` to find *all* User elements.

I'll stick with the former for the moment. That gives us:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> users =
            (from el in XMLDoc.Root.Elements("User")
             where (string) el.Attribute("GUID") == userGUID.ToString()
             select el);
```

Now, we can still tidy this up further. Firstly, let's cast to `Guid` instead of `string`:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> users =
    (from el in XMLDoc.Root.Elements("User")
     where (Guid) el.Attribute("GUID") == userGUID
     select el);
```

However there's not a lot of reason to use a query expression here... all you're applying is a single predicate. Let's just use the `Where` method directly:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> users = 
    XMLDoc.Root
          .Elements("User")
          .Where(el => (Guid) el.Attribute("GUID") == userGUID);
```

How you lay it out is up to you, of course :) With a longer line, you can probably align everything up under a longer first line:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> users = XMLDoc.Root
                                    . etc
```

Now, finally - what about if the User element doesn't have a GUID attribute? Currently, this code will throw an exception. That may be exactly what you want - or it may not. If it's not, you can make it ignore such things by casting to `Nullable<Guid>` aka `Guid?` instead:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> users = 
    XMLDoc.Root
          .Elements("User")
          .Where(el => (Guid?) el.Attribute("GUID") == userGUID);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was of great use too, too bad I can mark only one as correct.