# Getting all elements with a specific attribute in LINQ to XML

Tags: .net, xml, linq

I've been playing around with some linq to xml, and I'm having some problems parsing http://www.nationalbanken.dk/dndk/valuta.nsf/valuta-hist.xml , which is a list showing currency rates for the last five days, in danish.

I'm trying to get all the "cubes" here the attribute "currency" is equal to a specific value.

Until now, I have the following:

```
Stream stream = e.Result;
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
        var _rd = (from x in doc.Descendants("Cube")
                     where x.Attribute("currency").Value.Equals(SelectedCurrency.Instance.CurrencyCode)
                     select x).ToList();
```

Ofcause this kind of questions have been answered a lot of times before, but I can't figure of if it has something to do with the duplication of the element names, cause all I get is a blank null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find Elements by Attribute using XDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678251/find-elements-by-attribute-using-xdocument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not using namespaces for parsing the xml.

```
XNamespace ns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";
var _rd = (from x in doc.Descendants(ns+"Cube")
           where x.Attribute("currency").Value.Equals(SelectedCurrency.Instance.CurrencyCode)
           select x).ToList();
```

Something along these lines should work.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Thank you... Apparently I get a NullReference when I try to do as you suggested, so I added `.Where(i => i.Attribute("currency") != null)`, and then I again get nothing, but not an exception...

Comment: Actually, it did work. Just me that screwed another value up. Thank you very much... Marked as answer...