# How to return an Element when all we know is an Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlarchivefieldlist archive_schema="47800727">
   <client key_id="47800731"  str_label="Customer" str_type="select" invoice="1"/>
   <brand key_id="47800734" str_label="BrandName" str_type="text" invoice="2"/>
   <product key_id="47800730" str_label="Product" str_type="text" invoice="3"/>
</xmlarchivefieldlist>
```

I have the document in an XDocument.

How do I find the Element name when I know only an Attribute value.

e.g. I know str_label="Customer" so I want returned:- client.
e.g. I know str_type="text" so I want returned:- brand, product.

Comment: Take a look at this post seems to be very similar to your question,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678251/find-elements-by-attribute-using-xdocument.

Comment: No I read that one.  It already know the element name.  I'm looking for the element name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML with XPath to get element by attribute value:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var names = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//*[@str_label='Customer']")
                .Select(e => e.Name);
```

Or  you can use lambda syntax:

```
string attrName = "str_type";
string attrValue = "text";
var names = xdoc.Descendants()
                .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute(attributeName) == attrValue)
                .Select(e => e.Name);
```

BTW: To get concatenated string with names you can use String.Join:

```
var result = String.Join(",", names);
```

Comment: Note that you're always selecting a single element, the question clearly suggest there could be multiple

Comment: Thanks to all.  This one got me to the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
xdoc.Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("str_label") != null
              && x.Attribute("str_label").Value == "Customer")
    .Select(e => e.Name);
```

Comment: I suggest you to use explicit casting operator to get nullable types from attributes or elements - that will allow to skip null-check and getting value

Answer (score 0):

You want `.Attribute("str_label").Value`

Something like:

```
var filter = xDoc.Descendents("xmlarchivefieldlist").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("str_label") == "Customer");
```

Comment: @user2674389, why not?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the root element is `<xmlarchivefieldlist>` and that the element you're looking for is a child of that, you can do this:

```
var customer = doc.Element("xmlarchivefieldlist").Elements()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("str_label").Value == "Customer");
Console.WriteLine(customer);
<client key_id="47800731" str_label="Customer" str_type="select" invoice="1" />
```

To more generally look for any descendant elements that match, you can just do the following. This, unlike the above, does not require the elements it's looking at to have a `str_label` attribute.

```
var customer = doc.Descendants()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("str_label") == "Customer");
Console.WriteLine(customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath:

> name(//node()[@str_label='Customer'][1])

Will return the node-name 'client'