# How to get an xml node element value using XDocument?

Tags: asp.net, xml

Here I am listing an xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <dataitem>
        qqqqqqq
    </dataitem>
    <templatedata>
        <Year>2001</Year>
    </templatedata>
    <mailmergedata>
        <row>
            <facilityname>ABC Corporation</facilityname>
            <dueamount>200.00</dueamount>
        </row>
        <row>
            <facilityname>XYZ Corporation</facilityname>
            <DueAmount>50.00</DueAmount>
        </row>
    </mailmergedata>
</data>
```

I want to retrive the value of the node facilityname
Anybody pls help

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load("xml file path");
var query = from c in xmlFile.Descendants("facilityname ") select c;
```

then

```
foreach (XElement element in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element); // get your value here
}
```

Refer Job Skeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/566180/770710), that may help you ..

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [XPathSelectElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.xpathselectelements%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and then use XPath to navigate:

```
xdoc.XPathSelectElements("/data/mailmergedata/row/facilityname")
```

Comment: And you have to remember to add: using System.Xml.XPath.