# Add event in ResourceDictionary Controls

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have to add events in Controls which reides in ResourceDictionary ex. List SelectionChanged Image Tap etc, please suggest how cna i do this

**Views-> MainPage.XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}">
  <phone:Panorama Name="Container" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                  Background="{StaticResource AppBackground}" TitleTemplate="{StaticResource AppPanoramaTitle}">

      <phone:PanoramaItem Name="GetGalleryItem" Content="{Binding GetGalleryModel}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GetGalleryContent}"/>
  </phone:Panorama>
```

**Views->DataTemplates->GetGallery.XAML**

```
                        <Image Source="{Binding THUMB, Converter = {StaticResource ThumbnailConverter}, ConverterParameter = 120}" Width="120" x:Name="testTap"
                               Height="120" Stretch="Fill" />

                    <Image Source="{Binding CategoryImage}" Width="130" Height="130" Stretch="Fill" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:LongListSelectorEx.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:LongListSelectorEx>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: For the tap event in your image, you could the `tap` key work within your `Image` tag.

Answer (score 0):

For the tap event in your image, you could use the `tap` key work within your `Image` tag. such as

Xaml:

```
<Image Tap="tap_image" Source="{Binding THUMB, Converter = {StaticResource ThumbnailConverter}, ConverterParameter = 120}" Width="120" x:Name="testTap"
                           Height="120" Stretch="Fill" />
```

.cs

```
  private void tap_image(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
         //do whatever you wanted
        }
```

Yes you could use the `SelectionChanged` event for a listbox or a longlistselector. 
Have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152645/windows-phone-7-listbox-selectionchanged-event)

Hope it helps