# Get name of collection item in a config

Tags: c#

there is a web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="something" />
      <add name="target" path="*" verb="*" type="Custom.Handler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And I need to obtain, in Custom.Handler class, name of the add element, "target" in the example. Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading settings from app.config or web.config in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net)

Comment: No, it does not. I'm able to read whole system.webServer section by ConfigurationManager.GetSection, but I can't get handlers or handler names from it. I need exactly name of added handler.

Comment: Try this in that case : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58437486/8763644

Comment: It's an option, but also I want to know if is there some option without such extra parsing.