# Get null everytime if I try to get XML value C#

Tags: c#, xml

I try to get the value of "firstName" of the following XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Userlist xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <user username="Max.mix" id="464" adult="true">
    <registeredBy>Internet</registeredBy>
    <firstName>Max</firstName>
    <birthday>15031975</birthday>
  </user>
  <user username="Sus.lab" id="125" adult="false">
    <registeredBy>Phone</registeredBy>
    <firstName>Susanne</firstName>
    <birthday>03112007</birthday>
  </user>
</Userlist >
```

But I get everytime a empty (null) value back with this method:

```
public List<List> GetFirstName()
        {
            const string filename = @"C:\XML.xml";

            string text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(text);

            List<List> firstnameList = doc.Root.Elements().Select(x => new List
            {
                firstName = (string)x.Element("firstName"),
            }).ToList();

            return firstnameList ;

        } 

public class List
    {
        public string firstName{ get; set; }

    }
```

Where I have the Problem?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that `doc.Element()` only returns the top level, i.e. "user".  You want to search for "firstName" at *ANY* level. One alternative might be to try `doc.Descendants("firstName")`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566167/query-an-xdocument-for-elements-by-name-at-any-depth

Comment: As a general debugging tip: You should break apart your one-liner statement into multiple statements then run a `foreach` loop instead of `Select`.  This way you can place breakpoints and see what the values are at each step.  Once you've figured out what the structure is and where you've gone wrong you can re-condense it (or not).

Answer (score 0):

`XElement.Elements` only returns the top-level elements, not all nested elements.

See docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=netcore-3.1

I think you may want `GetDescendantNodes()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendantnodes?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_DescendantNodes

Answer (score 0):

```
    public List<string> GetFirstNames()
    {
        const string filename = @"C:\XML.xml";

        string text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(text);
        List<string> firstnameList =
            doc.Root.Elements().Select(x => x.Element("firstName").Value).ToList();

        return firstnameList;
    }
```

Comment: What I get is an System.NullReferenceException with this method.

Comment: It works with the test file you supplied.  You can add the necessary null check to the select if all the "user" elements in your real file do not contain a "firstName" element.

Comment: Can you give me a sample for this: List<List> firstnameList = doc.Root.Elements().Select(x => new List
            {
                firstName = (string)x.Element("firstName"),
            }).ToList();
Because I have everytime a strange value. So I mean not the correct value.